# Loading json array from text file

Tags: jquery, json, dojo, get

Im using jquery and dojo to search a json string

```
   $.get('json.txt', function(data) { //alert(data); works fine

      dojo.require("dojox.json.query");
      query = "(product_tonnage = "+$('#slider-tonnage-value').val()+")";
      var json_db = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

      var results = "";
      results = dojox.json.query(query, json_db);
             alert(results.length); //it must contain 4 results
      });
```

How ever im getting the error "JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data"

Comment: What is the contents of json.txt?

Comment: Can you post some sample JSON data?

Comment: Its a long json string(and its a valid json) ..how ever i cant post here its too big to post..

Comment: In that case, I suggest trimming it down to the minimum that still causes the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's `$.get()` method (and other Ajax methods) will parse the JSON for you (assuming the MIME type of the response is right). You can also add a "json" parameter to the end of your `$.get()` call to explicitly tell jQuery you expect JSON back.

Calling `JSON.parse()` yourself will then try to parse an (already parsed) object rather than the JSON string.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.get('json.txt', function(data) {
      dojo.require("dojox.json.query");
      query = "(product_tonnage = "+$('#slider-tonnage-value').val()+")";
      var json_db = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
      var results = "";
      results = dojox.json.query(query, json_db);
      alert(results.length);
}, 'json');
```

Please try this and see if it works.